# I used v-for the router-link but it‘s not worked

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

```
<li v-for="item in navbars">
    <router-link to="{path:item.router}">{{item.names}}</router-link>
</li>
```

but it does not work, the console is

vue-router.esm.js?f926:16 [vue-router] Duplicate named routes definition: { name: "auto", path: "/auto" }

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isShow: false,
      navbars: [
        {names: 'xx', router: '/xx'},
        {names: 'xx', router: '/xx'},
        {names: 'xx', router: '/xx'},
        {names: 'xx', router: '/xx'},
        {names: 'xx', router: '/xx'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your route definition object look like?

Comment: I edit this question

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having `to` change into `:to`. A good practice would be to use `:key="i"` including `v-for="(item, i) in navbars"` due to performance reasons.

A note from someone else visiting this question and having `:href` in its code - you need to change `:href` into `:to`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **router-link**:

```
<li v-for="item in navbars" v-bind:key="item.id">
        <router-link :to="{path:item.router}">{{item.names}}</router-link>
</li>
```

or if you use **href**:

```
  <li v-for="item in navbars" v-bind:key="item.id">                    
      <a :href="item.router">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
```

You can add `id` to `navbars`

```
 export default {
      data () {
        return {
          isShow: false,
          navbars: [
            {names: 'xx', router: '/xx', id: 1},
            {names: 'xx', router: '/xx', id: 2},
            {names: 'xx', router: '/xx', id: 3},
            {names: 'xx', router: '/xx', id: 4},
            {names: 'xx', router: '/xx', id: 5}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use v-bind when you use javascript expression:

```
 <router-link :to="{path:item.router}">{{item.names}}</router-link>
```

[vue router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html)